# Wait notify multithreading producer consumer issue

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, producer-consumer, notify

I was working on a basic thread-producer consumer problem.

now in my this code what i am assuming is 
1) The threads will go to wait state initially and the moment any task comes one of the tasks will be notified and it will process that task and then again wait but my threads are going to runnable states abruptly. Is my understanding correct?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    AsyncTaskExecutorImpl executorImpl = new AsyncTaskExecutorImpl(10, 5);

    for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {

        Runnable task = new createTask();
        System.out.println("Added task no" + i);
        executorImpl.execute(task, 10);
    }
}



import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;

public class MyArrayBlockingQueue<T> {
private volatile ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable> internalTaskQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(
        10);


public boolean isEmpty() {
    synchronized (this) {
        return internalTaskQueue.isEmpty();
    }
}

public void add(Runnable paramRunnable) throws InterruptedException {
    synchronized (this.internalTaskQueue) {
        this.internalTaskQueue.put(paramRunnable);
        this.internalTaskQueue.notifyAll();

    }

    for (Thread t : Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet()) {
        if (t.getName().startsWith("T") || t.getName().startsWith("M")) {
            System.out.println(t.getName() + "----" + t.getState());
        }
    }

}

public Runnable poll() {

    Runnable task = null;
    try {
        synchronized (this.internalTaskQueue) {
            while (this.internalTaskQueue.isEmpty()) {

                this.internalTaskQueue.wait();

            }
            task = this.internalTaskQueue.poll();
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return task;
}
}`
 import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
 import java.util.concurrent.Future;

 import org.springframework.core.task.AsyncTaskExecutor;

 public class AsyncTaskExecutorImpl implements AsyncTaskExecutor {

private  MyArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable> taskQueue= new MyArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>();

// Here we are creating a Thread pool of number of threads required
public AsyncTaskExecutorImpl(int no_of_threads, int taskQueueSize) {

    for (int i = 0; i < no_of_threads; i++) {
        IndividualThread thread = new IndividualThread(this.taskQueue);
        thread.start();
    }

    for (Thread t : Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet()) {
        if (t.getName().startsWith("T") || t.getName().startsWith("M")) {
            System.out.println(t.getName() + "----" + t.getState());
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void execute(Runnable paramRunnable, long paramLong) {
    if (paramRunnable instanceof Runnable) {

        // pick any thread from the threadpool and then execute that
        try {
            this.taskQueue.add(paramRunnable);

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}`
class CreateTask implements Runnable {
@Override
public void run() {

    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "got the task");

}
```

Comment: What is this line `new createTask();`? Can class names start with lower case?

Comment: @selalerer  yes its a class kindly ignore that typo error. i have added CreateTask class.

Comment: @AnilSharma what is your question exactly? Is there an error in the code or do you want to understand how it works?

Comment: @Dien  my code is  working but abruptly. If i increase the number of tasks to 300 or any higher number. then my threads go to Runnable ..As per my thinking threads should only be waiting. I mean only one thread should execute task and then again go to wait. So all the threads should be in waiting. but  sometimes alll threads are going to runnable state

Comment: If only one thread is running and all others are waiting, CPU is under utilized. The purpose of multi threading is defeated.  You should not have any issues with multi-threading unless you are not getting excepted result or data is not thread-safe. If application is behaving properly with multi-threading, you should not worry on how many threads are running.

Comment: Is this just for learning or why don't you use BlockingQueue's blocking methods and get rid of wait/notifying yourself?

Comment: Yeah, But  i want to know the reason. In future if i have the need to use another queue structure. So you can consider it for learning only ;). but provide me the clarification :)

Answer (score 0):

NotifyAll would "wake up" all waiting threads. But it should be logically ok because they would then compete to get into 'sychronized' block , the 1st thread that gets access will find 'not empty', pull the data, exit the 'synchornized' block.
Then some other thread would get into the synchronized block, but by then it would see 'empty' & immediately get back to waiting (unless there were several 'add' actions, of course, in which case several threads would see 'not empty'). In other words, if your spin lock is correctly designed, threads would become Runnable for a brief fraction of a second.

There's also 'Object.notify' that would wake up only one thread, but AFAIK it's considered unsafe for spin-locks such as yours.

Comment: `Object.notify()` is there for a reason, and it is safe to use if you use it the way it was intended.  Most of the questions about `wait()` and `notify()` on this board come from people who do not realize that `wait()` and `notify()` are _low level_ primitives that are meant to be used in a very specific pattern.  Most of the people who write `wait()` and `notify()` calls are re-inventing higher-level classes that have been available from the java.util.concurrent package and from third-party libraries for quite a while now.

Comment: knowing internal details of something and trying to build something from scratch increases our understanding about that thing. I disagree with ur statement. We should reuse the code but we should never hide behind the already developed logic. :)

There should never be any hesitation about getting our hands dirty.